# Adding size attributes to <img> doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```
$("#myId").html(
    "<img src='" + 
    $(xml).find("picture").text() +
    "' height="42" width="42"></img>"
);
```

It works fine until I add the `'height="42" width="42"'` text. Why is this? Can't you add size attributes like this?

Comment: The javascript has syntax errors. You need to either use apostrophes `'42'` or escape the quotes `\"42\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the string with `"` therefore any that you contain within the string must be escaped as well with `\`

```
$("#myId").html(
   "<img src='" + 
   $(xml).find("picture").text() +
   "' height=\"42\" width=\"42\"/>"
);
```

Comment: It will be not bad to mention that `</img>` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ahhh, I can't believe I didn't notice that! Thank you so much, that fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

In reality you should be doing it this way:

```
$("#myId").html($('<img/>', {
    src: $(xml).find("picture").text(),
    css: {
        height: '42px',
        width: '42px'
    }
}))
```

Comment: Wow, that does look a lot better. Thanks you!

Comment: This approach of element's creation indeed looks better than string concatenations.

Comment: Yep cleaner method. I would definitely recommend this to anyone doing lightweight DOM injection. However, for loops on large data, this is not ideal given that the construction of the jQuery element would have to occur each time you wanted to append. This would cause a huge performance degradation. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

```
"' height="42" width="42"></img>"
```

In this part you opening with " and closing it after the first = from height.